# jquery is not sending date in query string

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have this html code.

```
<form class="" role="form">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="streams">Select Stream</label>
            <select name="streams" id="streams" class="form-control">
                <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                <?php
                    while($streamRow = mysql_fetch_array($streamResult)) {
                        echo
                            "<option value=".$streamRow[0].">".$streamRow[1]."</option>";
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="branches">Select Branch</label>
            <select name="branches" id="branches" class="form-control">
                <option value="">-- Select --</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="batches">Select Batch</label>
            <select name="batches" id="batches" class="form-control">
                <option value="">-- Select --</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div class="form-group divBefore">
            <label for="divisionBefore">Div</label>
            <select name="divisionBefore" id="divisionBefore" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Sel</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group divAfter hide">
            <label for="division">Div</label>
            <select name="division" id="division" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Sel</option>
                <?php
                    $divisionResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM division");
                    while($divisionRow = mysql_fetch_array($divisionResult)) {
                        echo
                            "<option value=".$divisionRow[0].">".$divisionRow[1]."</option>";
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div class="form-group semesterBefore">
            <label for="semBefore">Sem</label>
            <select name="semBefore" id="semBefore" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Sel</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group semesterAfter hide">
            <label for="sem">Sem</label>
            <select name="sem" id="sem" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Sel</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div class="form-group subject">
            <label for="subject">Select Subject</label>
            <select name="subject" id="subject" class="form-control">
                <option value="">-- Select --</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--<div class="col-lg-2" id="lecBefore">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="subject">Select Lecture</label>
            <select name="lect" id="lect" class="form-control">
                <option value="">-- Select --</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 hide" id="lecAfter">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="subject">Select Lecture</label>
            <select name="lecture" id="lecture" class="form-control">
                <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                <option value="1">Lecture 1</option>
                <option value="2">Lecture 2</option>
                <option value="3">Lecture 3</option>
                <option value="4">Lecture 4</option>
                <option value="5">Lecture 5</option>
                <option value="6">Lecture 6</option>
                <option value="7">Lecture 7</option>
                <option value="8">Lecture 8</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>-->
    <div class="col-lg-2 hide" id="date">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="dateNow">Start Date</label> <br>
            <div class="input-group date" id="avsDate">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="avsDateTxt" id="avsDateTxt" readonly value="<?php echo date('d-m-Y');?>"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 hide" id="date1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="dateNow">End Date</label> <br>
            <div class="input-group date" id="endDate">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="endDateTxt" id="endDateTxt" readonly value="<?php echo date('d-m-Y');?>"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and my jquery is.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sidebar-menu .attnd').addClass('active');
    $('.sidebar-menu .attnd .genExcel').addClass('active');
    $(".sidebar-menu .attnd").tree();
    $('#streams').change(function() {
        $('#branches').html("<option value=''>-- Select --</option>");
        $('#batches').html("<option value=''>-- Select --</option>");
        $('.divAfter').hide();
        $('.divBefore').show();
        $('.semesterAfter').hide();
        $('.semesterBefore').show();
        $('#date').hide();
        $('#date1').hide();
        $('#lecAfter').hide();
        $('#lecBefore').show();
        $('#studManip').html('');
        if($(this).val() != '')
            $.streamSelection($(this).val());
    });
    $('#branches').change(function() {
        $('#batches').html("<option value=''>-- Select --</option>");
        $('.divAfter').hide();
        $('.divBefore').show();
        $('.semesterAfter').hide();
        $('.semesterBefore').show();
        $('#date').hide();
        $('#date1').hide();
        $('#lecAfter').hide();
        $('#lecBefore').show();
        $('#studManip').html('');
        if($(this).val() != '')
            $.branchSelection($(this).val());
    });
    $('#batches').change(function() {
        $('.divAfter').hide();
        $('.divBefore').show();
        $('.semesterAfter').hide();
        $('.semesterBefore').show();
        $('#date').hide();
        $('#date1').hide();
        $('#lecAfter').hide();
        $('#lecBefore').show();
        $('#studManip').html('');
        if($(this).val() != '') {
            $.listSemester($(this).val());
            $('.divBefore').hide();
            $('#division').val('');
            $('.divAfter').show();
        }
    });
    $('#division').change(function() {
        $('.studList').hide();
        $('.semesterAfter').hide();
        $('.semesterBefore').show();
        $('#date').hide();
        $('#date1').hide();
        $('#lecAfter').hide();
        $('#lecBefore').show();
        $('#studManip').html('');
        if($(this).val() != '') {
            $('.semesterBefore').hide();
            $('#sem').val('');
            $('.semesterAfter').show();
        }
    });
    $('#sem').change(function() {
        $('#date').hide();
        $('#date1').hide();
        $('#lecAfter').hide();
        $('#lecBefore').show();
        $('#studManip').html('');
        if($(this).val() != '')
            $.searchSubject();
    });
    $('#subject').change(function() {
        if($(this).val() != '') {
            $.when($('#date').show())
            .then($('#date1').show())
            .then($('.btnExcel').show());
        }
    });
    /*$('#lecture').change(function() {
        $.when($('#date').hide())
        .then($('#studManip').html(''));
        if($(this).val() != '') {
            $('#date').show();
            $.when($.searchStudent())
            .then($('#studManip').show());
        }
    });*/
    $('#avsDate').datepicker({
        format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
        startDate: "01-01-2012",
        endDate: '<?php echo date('d-m-Y')?>',
        todayBtn: "linked",
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
    });
    $('#endDate').datepicker({
        format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
        startDate: "01-01-2012",
        endDate: '<?php echo date('d-m-Y')?>',
        todayBtn: "linked",
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
    });
    $('#avsDate').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(e) {
            $.when($('.btnExcel').attr('href', 'studExcel.php?streamId='+$('#streams').val()+'&branchId='+$('#branches').val()+'&batchId='+$('#batches').val()+'&divisionId='+$('#division').val()+'&semId='+$('#sem').val()+'&sDate='+$('#advDatetxt').val()+'&eDate='+$('#endDatetxt').val()))
            .then($('.btnExcel').show());
    });
    $('#endDate').change(function() {
            $.when($('.btnExcel').attr('href', 'studExcel.php?streamId='+$('#streams').val()+'&branchId='+$('#branches').val()+'&batchId='+$('#batches').val()+'&divisionId='+$('#division').val()+'&semId='+$('#sem').val()+'&sDate='+$('#advDatetxt').val()+'&eDate='+$('#endDatetxt').val()))
            .then($('.btnExcel').show());
    });
    /*var date = new Date();
    $('#avsDate').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(e) {
        $('#studManip').html('');
        if(weekday[$(this).datepicker('getDate').getUTCDay()] != 'Sunday'){
            $.when($.searchStudent())
            .then($('#studManip').show());
        } else
            alert('Today is Sunday');
    });*/
});
$.streamSelection = function(selStreamId) {
    $.ajax({
        url:"../student/searchBranch.php",
        data:{
            streamId:selStreamId,
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#branches').html(data);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}
$.branchSelection = function(selBranchId) {
    $.ajax({
        url:"../student/searchBatch.php",
        data:{
            branchId:selBranchId,
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#batches').html(data);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}
$.listSemester = function(selStreamId) {
    $.ajax({
        url:"../student/searchStream.php",
        data:{
            streamId:selStreamId,
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#sem').html(data);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}
$.searchSubject = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url:"searchSubject.php",
        data:{
            streamId    :   $('#streams').val(),
            branchId    :   $('#branches').val(),
            semId       :   $('#sem').val(),
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#subject').html(data);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}
```

every thing  is working fine but when I change **advDatetxt** or **endDatetxt** jquery won't sending value with query string and describe as indefined. When I put cursor on excel button it will display left bottom corner as.

[image: undefine variable]

Comment: what error are you getting in your browser?

Comment: This jquery spaghetti is crying for some frontend framework

Comment: Tom my last two variable are undefine when i click Genrate Excel button.

Comment: Unless there are iFrames involved (and I doubt it), it may just be a typo as mentioned in Hemakumar's answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think problem is only spell mistakes

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="avsDateTxt" id="avsDateTxt" readonly value="<?php echo date('d-m-Y');?>">
sDate='+$('#advDatetxt').val()
```

Here spell mistake in id value, change it as

```
sDate='+$('#avsDatetxt').val()
```

next one :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="endDateTxt" id="endDateTxt" readonly value="<?php echo date('d-m-Y');?>">
eDate='+$('#endDatetxt').val()
```

Here also spell mistake, change it as

```
eDate='+$('#endDateTxt').val()
```

Comment: Almost correct, but also a good find... Case of CaSeSeNsItIvE... He tried to get `#avsDatetxt` where in the DOM it is `#avsDateTxt `.

Answer (score 0):

Some of your IDs don't match with the selectors.

See this

```
id="avsDateTxt"
```

against

```
$('#advDatetxt')
```